# Open the ease of use cursor and pointer settings in Windows 10 with run box?

Tags: windows, ease-of-access

I've been looking around to see if there's any way to open the **ease of access>Cursor & pointer** settings in a batch file or via the run box using `start ms-settings:easeofaccess-mouse` for example will take me to the mouse setting and documented others here:

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-settings.html

On that website `start ms-settings:easeofaccess-display` works but it's undocumented.

I was trying with pot luck to get `easeofaccess-cursorpointer` etc to work but no luck.

So any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I cannot tag `windows-10` because I don't have enough rep. Go figure!

So that's what I'm running:

```
BuildNumber  Caption                   OSArchitecture  Version     

18363        Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  64-bit          10.0.18363
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to guess this and the way you do so is with:

`start ms-settings:easeofaccess-cursorandpointersize`

So my batch file looks like:

```
@echo off & cls
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
start ms-settings:easeofaccess-cursorandpointersize
exit
```

Comment: You have some documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app)